# I need to help at for or while loops

Tags: python

Create a scripts which will print the following, using for or while loops:

```
           # #
          ## ##
         ### ###
        #### ####
       ##### #####
      ###### ######
     ####### #######
    ######## ########
    ######## ########
     ####### #######
      ###### ######
       ##### #####
        #### ####
         ### ###
          ## ##
           # #
```

so this is pretty much my "Homework", can someone help me? i dont get it... i guess i wasn't listening to lection.. i have few more but im not posting them cuz i wanna do it by my self

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a 'do my homework for me', please show your efforts

Comment: just a tip maybe? or a hint how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

You should understand what a loop do.

- **For** : You can repeat similar action X times
- **While** : You can repeat similar action until a condition is verified.

If you want your exercise to works, then you only want to run a loop X times, and then run another loop X times.

The first loop for example, will print "#" X times, then a space, and "#" X times again. Each time you pass through the loop, X have to be incremented.

**Now, go update your post with some code so we can help you understand !**

Comment: Also worth noting: In a for loop, when you're doing the action you want to repeat, that action is allowed to know how many time it has already run so far. So e.g. it could print a different number each time. Or print a different number of hashes ...